# How to use CoreImage to create a smooth threshold filter?

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, cikernel

Are there existing filters that could be used as a smooth threshold? By this I mean that pixel values should be thresholded between two values, but the intermediate values are interpolated.

Basically, I'm trying to implement this:

https://www.filterforge.com/wiki/index.php/Thresholds#Interpolation_.28.22Blending.22.29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to write your own using Core Image Kernel Language and a `CIColorKernel`.

I would use a `smoothstep` and pass in two edge values along with the luminance of the current pixel. The CIKL could look something like this:

```
kernel vec4 color(__sample pixel, float inputEdgeO, float inputEdge1)
{
    float luma = dot(pixel.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
    float threshold = smoothstep(inputEdgeO, inputEdge1, luma);
    return vec4(threshold, threshold, threshold, 1.0);
}
```

You can wrap this into a `CIFilter` with the following code:

```
class SmoothThreshold: CIFilter
{
    var inputImage : CIImage?
    var inputEdgeO: CGFloat = 0.25
    var inputEdge1: CGFloat = 0.75

    var colorKernel = CIColorKernel(string:
        "kernel vec4 color(__sample pixel, float inputEdgeO, float inputEdge1)" +
        "{" +
        "    float luma = dot(pixel.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));" +
        "    float threshold = smoothstep(inputEdgeO, inputEdge1, luma);" +
        "    return vec4(threshold, threshold, threshold, 1.0);" +
        "}"
    )

    override var outputImage: CIImage!
    {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage,
            colorKernel = colorKernel else
        {
            return nil
        }

        let extent = inputImage.extent
        let arguments = [inputImage,
                         inputEdgeO,
                         inputEdge1]

        return colorKernel.applyWithExtent(extent,
                                           arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to ensure `inputEdge0` is less than `inputEdge1`, or the `smoothstep` will go a little crazy. You may want to `saturate` them too, to ensure they're between 0 and 1.

Have a look at `CIFilter.registerFilterName` which will allow you to create an instance of `SmoothThreshold` with familiar syntax, although this will work fine:

```
let image = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "monalisa.jpg")!)!

let filter = SmoothThreshold()
filter.inputImage = image

let final = filter.outputImage
```

Cheers!

Simon

Comment: Thanks! I was mostly interested in the algorithm since I'm familiar with creating kernels. Why do you compare the luma channel? (I'm only interested in comparing the average of the RGB values but I'm still curious as to the reason behind luma).

Comment: Depends on the use case: if it's thresholding by perceived brightness, averaging isn't quite right. Pure green (0,1,0) is a lot brighter that pure blue (0,0,1) but have the same average values.

Comment: Yeah, makes total sense. At the end of the day I was just trying to accomplish what is described here: https://www.filterforge.com/wiki/index.php/Thresholds#Interpolation_.28.22Blending.22.29

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me:

```
[CIColorKernel kernelWithString:
              @"kernel vec4 threshold(__sample s, float thresh) {\n"
                "float avg = (s.r + s.g + s.b) / 3.0;\n"
                "float val = smoothstep(0.0, thresh, avg);"
                "return vec4(val, val, val, 1.0);\n}"];
```